# ES6 + jasny-bootstrap - Error: Cannot find module jasny-bootstrap?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, ecmascript-6, jasny-bootstrap

How can I import jasny-bootstrap into my ES6 class?

ES6:

```
'use strict';

import $ from 'jquery';
import jasny from 'jasny-bootstrap';

class PushMenu {
    constructor() {
        this.slideShown = false;
        $('.navmenu').on('shown.bs.offcanvas', () => {
            this.slideShown = true;
        });
    }
}
```

I get an error when I try to compile it with gulp:

```
{ Error: Cannot find module 'jasny-bootstrap' from '/var/www/my-project/js'
```

I am sure I have already installed it with npm following [its npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasny-bootstrap):

```
npm install jasny-bootstrap
```

Any ideas why and how to resolve this?

**EDIT:**

I managed to load it manually with the full path:

```
import jasny from '../node_modules/jasny-bootstrap/dist/js/jasny-bootstrap';
```

But it does **not** work with no error hinted.

**EDIT 2:**

I have tried to glue it with:

```
jQueryBridget('jasny', Jasny, $);
```

but still no luck. Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'option' of undefined

The entire code:

```
'use strict';

import $ from 'jquery';
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
import Jasny from '../node_modules/jasny-bootstrap/dist/js/jasny-bootstrap.js';
import jQueryBridget from 'jquery-bridget';

jQueryBridget('jasny', Jasny, $);

class PushMenu {
    constructor() {
        this.slideShown = false;
        $('.navmenu').on('shown.bs.offcanvas', () => {
            this.slideShown = true;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: does it truly exist if you go into that folder?  What if you declared the full path in the import? `import jasny from '/full-path'`

Comment: `does it truly exist if you go into that folder?` yes it is in the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: After the other question about masonry you now must understand that just importing a dependency does not make it automatically work with the instance of jquery. There should be some glue layer between the two. PS: nope, I don't know it, I never worked with either jasny or masonry. There is a chance no one implemented it yet - so it's your chance to contribute into the opensource :-)

Comment: @zerkms I have tried to glue it with `jQueryBridget('jasny', Jasny, $);` but still no luck.

Comment: Not sure what `Jasny` refers to, there is no such variable in your code. Provide the **complete** code for your last attempt. Also, I'm not aware on how all these libraries work internally, there is a chance the `jasny` is simply not compatible with `jQueryBridget`. In that case you need help from `jasny` developers or make it compatible yourself.

Comment: @zerkms I have updated my edit. It might have to be glued to bootstrap not to jquery.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work with ES6 `import` but works with:

```
<script src="vendor/jasny-bootstrap/jasny-bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Then without importing it:

```
class PushMenu {
    constructor() {
        this.slideShown = false;
        $('.navmenu').on('shown.bs.offcanvas', () => {
            this.slideShown = true;
        });
    }
}
```

Not ideal.